# Price Rounding to nearest 5c

Tags: mysql, rounding

i have an sql script that calculates the discount for items, now while i can do the calculation just fine i'm running into the problem for cents in the price

i have an item which is $9.95, the discount to it is 50% so it's new price is $4.975, since prices in the store should have a precision of 2 the value would be $4.97 (according to policy, discounted prices must be the lowest value)

problem is that the value is wrong, since prices on the website have to match what's in store and since in Australia the smallest change is 5 cents a price has to be a multiple of of that since a cashier can't give a customer 1 - 4 cents change and people will complain if they buy an item online that was discounted to $4.97 and in store it's $4.95 (yes, people are that picky)

is there a way to round to the nearest 5 or 0

Comment: What are you yabbering on about? In our great land downunder, you generally only buy online with credit/debit cards and they're perfectly capable of transacting on a sub-5c resoultion. In fact, if you buy something at (eg) Woolies for $14.99 with a card, that's what you're charged. It's only when you're paying cash does the rounding come into effect and I'm not sure how you're doing that over the web. It should be 4.97 in the shop as well.

Comment: @paxdiablo i am well aware of that, i'm Australian too, however the items on the site has the same listing as those actually in the store so how much a person would pay in store, in cash, has to be the same on the site, discounting on tellers do this correction even if the buyer is using a card so i have to do the same on the site....lucky, this only applies to discounts by a percentage since everything in store is normally priced at either 0 or 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
SELECT floor(price_after_discount * 20) / 20 AS price FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server I can do:

```
select 
    Val, 
    FLOOR(val) + 
        CASE 
            WHEN (val * 100)%100 >= 50 THEN 0.05 
            ELSE 0 
        END Rounded_Val
from #Test
```

[image]